# Scrapy CrawlProcess is throwing reactor already installed

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

I have N workers in paralell (instantiated from docker) that trigger a scrapy crawl from a script via `CrawlProcess`. Why is it that I am getting this error: `error: reactor already installed`?  I simply have a function:

```
def foo():
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    stats = process.crawl(**kwargs, stats_callback=lambda stats: stats)
    process.start()
```

Shouldn't scrapy run a crawl in a separate process and the reactor will have to be reinstalled?

I don't want to use `crawlRunner` why is this occuring?

and scrapy: **Scrapy==2.6.1**

Comment: CrawlerProcess doesn't start a process, no.

Comment: "My Twisted version: Scrapy==2.6.1" does not seem correct.